# Anonymous type in Repeater DataBound event

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, anonymous-types, databound

I'm setting the DataSource of an ASP.NET repeater as follows:

```
rptTargets.DataSource = from t in DB.SalesTargets select new { t.Target, t.SalesRep.RepName };
```

Now, in the repeater's OnDataBound event, how can I retrieve the RepName and Target properties from the anonymous type contained in e.Item.DataItem?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [DataBinder.Eval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe.aspx):

```
string repName = (string)DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "RepName");
string target = (string)DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Target");
```

Answer (score 13):

I know this question has been answered over a year ago, but I've just found a .NET 4.0 solution for this problem.

When you bind your anonymous type to a repeater, you can access the properties in the OnDataBound event like this:

```
dynamic targetInfo = e.Item.DataItem as dynamic;

string repName = targetInfo.RepName;
string target = targetInfo.Target;
```

Comment: What if i have to put a condition on he member from targetInfo like if(targetinfo.RepName =="") then? how to put a condition ? because it gives me an exception that it doesn't have any type like this

Comment: In that case you should probably do something like `string repName = targetInfo.RepName; if (repName == "") { ... }`